# Custom font not working with Calligraphy library in Android

Tags: android

I want to put a custom font in my app but it's not working at all...

This is the MainActivity.java :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/SourceSansPro-Black.ttf")
                .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                .build()
        );

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }
```

This is the styles.xml :

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.Widget.TextView</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Widget"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.Widget.TextView" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.TextView">
        <item name="fontPath">fonts/a.ttf</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

My app is working with the minSDK version 23 and SDK target 25.

Comment: Shold you be applying fontPath to Views and not in Style ?

Comment: To views ? in my TextView ?

Comment: Yes, a glimpse to GitHub of the Library, i saw him use fontPath to a TextView, which makes sense, since you want to apply font there. Check it out on the devs GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I understand why it was not working !
This is because the fonts where not in the good folder (**assets** and not **assets/fonts** ).